# Watch HTTP traffic with Katana

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, fiddler

I'm launching OWIN/Katana from within MsTest.  I'm using the Web API HttpClient to create requests and I'm successfully receiving replies.

However, Fiddler doesn't see the traffic.  I've tried a number of techniques to make Fiddler see the traffic:

- Changed the host address to `localhost.` with an explicit period at the end
- Changed the host address to `localhost.fiddler`
- Changed the host address to match the machine name.

In each case the request/response is working, but still Fiddler does not see the traffic.

Perhaps in the end I should not try Fiddler. Is there another way to capture the raw HTTP traffic?

Comment: Fiddler works as a proxy, you need to set the proxy in the HttpClient and use localhost. Also set Fiddler to capture all processes

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the request URL's hostname to `localhost.fiddler` and it succeeded, that means, *by definition* that the traffic went through Fiddler. If you didn't see it in Fiddler, that means you have a filter set. In Fiddler, click Help > Troubleshoot to unhide hidden traffic. Look at the Sessions' `Comments` column to see which filter you have set that is hiding the traffic.